# How to Embind multiple cpp files in the Emscripten compiler?

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, emscripten, embind

I have two cpp files called in the Main.cpp file. This code is to be called from the ams.js file. I'm using the Embind Compiler to call WASM from JS.

Here is my sample code:

**class.h:**

```
class CLASS{
public:
int VARIABLE;
void FUNCTION();
};
```

**class.cpp:**

```
#include "CLASS.h"
void CLASS::FUNCTION()
{
VARIABLE = 5;

std::cout << "out : "+VARIABLE << std::endl;
}
```

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
#include "CLASS.h"
using namespace emscripten;
class MyClass
{
public:
MyClass(int x)
: x(x)

{}
int getCharCount(std::string strKey)
{
CLASS a;
a.FUNCTION();

return 0;

}

private:
int x;

 };

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_class_example) {

 class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
 .constructor<int>()
 .function("getCharCount", &MyClass::getCharCount);
    
 }
```

For compiling:

```
emcc --bind Main.cpp -o main.js
```

Calling the function in Render.js:

```
  var instance = new Module.MyClass();
  if (instance){
  var mainee  =  instance.getCharCount("hi")
  console.log("Somrthing is There");
  }else{
  console.log("Somrthing Wrong");
  }
  instance.delete();
```

Output error:

```
main3.js:2780 Uncaught BindingError: Tried to invoke ctor of MyClass with invalid number of parameters (0) - expected (1) parameters instead!
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate compilation.

```
emcc --bind -c class.cpp
emcc --bind -c main.cpp
emcc --bind class.o main.o -o main.js
```

But BindingError is caused by `new Module.MyClass();`, try `new Module.MyClass(123);`.

Comment: hii thanks for the reply when its comes to an big module for example i have one module contains 100 cpp files, i tried ur method find at final stage i cant generate js files its getting Linking error how to fix that bro

Comment: ok give me some idea i.e how do i link my libraries while compling, to be clear i converted all my cpp files to .o files then i have two libs calls configure.lib and curl.lib how do i compile all to gether in single output file because of not included lib files my call getting failure

Comment: You might need to build curl.lib and configure.lib from source as emscripten doesnot provide these libraries for web. For curl you can write new functions and map it to ajax calls (when you are compiling for web). I am not sure about your usecase of the configure.lib. Just to add curl.lib and configure.lib will not work as is with emscripten